# WPF binding not working properly with properties of int type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am having a property of `int` type in my view model which is bound to a `TextBox`. Everything works properly, `TwoWay` binding works fine except in one case -

If I clear the value of `TextBox`, property setter doesn't gets called and although value is cleared in `TextBox`, property still holds the previous value.

has anyone faced similar issue? is there any workaround for this?

Here is the property -

```
public int MaxOccurrences
{
    get
    {
        return this.maxOccurrences;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.maxOccurrences != value)
        {
            this.maxOccurrences = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("MaxOccurrences");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am binding the property in xaml -

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MaxOccurrences, Mode=TwoWay, 
    NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
```

Comment: I am curious to know whether this behavior is same in silverlight or not? Anyone!

Comment: Same behavior in Silverlight, except for data binding properties like NotifyOnSourceUpdated and UpdateSourceTrigger that aren't supported in Silverlight.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the similar problem.

You just need to update the code as:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MaxOccurrences, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty},
NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
```

Comment: `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: for .net 3.5 or above, try `TargetNullValue=''`

Answer (score 6):

This is partially a guess (I haven't got VS handy right now to try it out), but I think it's because a cleared text box is an empty `string` (`""`), which can't be implicitly converted to an `int`. You should probably implemented a type converter to provide the conversion for you. (you probably want to do something like convert "" to 0)

Comment: Easiest way to check -- run your project in Visual Studio and watch the Output window (View-Output). When you clear the textbox, you should see the Binding error Simon is talking about.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use a `Nullable` `integer`, you can use a `converter` that converts the empty `string` to 0, see the code below:

```
public class EmptyStringToZeroConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())
            ? 0
            : value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, but this solution was already mentioned by 'Simon' a year back.

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, I found this value converter (http://www.codecisions.com/custom-ivalueconverter-for-binding-a-wpf-textbox-to-an-integer/) kept the textbox showing as empty rather than changing it to a zero in the foreground as this answer seems to do. Obviously depends on requirements as to which you go for.

Answer (score 1):

Akjoshi, I have a working solution!

You need to change your integer property to `Naullable<int>` (i.e. `int?` ), see the following snippet:

```
private int? _maxOccurrences;
public int? MaxOccurrences
{
    get { return _maxOccurrences; }
    set { _maxOccurrences = value; }
}
```

You also need to add a value converter to convert the empty string to null value, see the following code snippet:

```
public class EmptyStringToNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())
            ? null
            : value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="ProgGridSelection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgGridSelection"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="136" Width="525"
    Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:EmptyStringToNullConverter x:Key="EmptyStringToNullConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Using Empty String to Null Converter"/>
    <TextBox Name="empNameTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=MaxOccurrences,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToNullConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[Note: this is just a proof of concept, and for the sake of simplicity I didn't use any patterns or best practices]

Answer (score 0):

It's because an `int` value can't be `null`.
It's best to use a `string` property that converts the value for you within your code to the required int property field.

That way you can perform a

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
  this.intValue = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Have a +1 from me. Although I think the preferred way would be a type converter rather than a duplicate property.

Comment: Thank you. I only asked in case I had missed something. Constructive criticism is always welcome as how else do we learn from our mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I need to handle and not numeric value to. I use the following converter for this:

```
public class StringFormatToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{            
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
          return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if(value is string)
       {
           var inttext = 
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace((string)value, "[^.0-9]", "");

           int number;
           return Int32.TryParse(inttext, out  number) ? number : 0;
       }
       else
       {
           return value;
       }
    }
}
```