# Silverlight datagrid twoway binding

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0

I have datagrid in which one of the column is Textbox control, have set the binding as twoway. the grid is binded to a observable collection. 
Issue : If I enter some value in text box, collection get populated. now if I clears that textbox the same has not been reflected to the collection. my binded property is nullable.

Thanks N Advance

Comment: clearing the TextBox should make the property "Empty", and not "null". Can you verify if that's what's happenning?

Comment: For string field it is making it as empty but in case of integer i am getting this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Output window in Visual Studio for binding errors. You should see a warning that there is no implicit conversion from an empty string to an Integer.

You could use a ValueConverter to perform this task.

See this related question for other approaches. Note that some may not apply as the focus there is WPF.

[WPF binding not working properly with properties of int type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199149/wpf-binding-not-working-properly-with-properties-of-int-type)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding BUApprovalQty, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=''}"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your problem might be exactly, but I've tried the following and it works as expected:

I have a simple Person class:

```
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name == value)
                return;
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    private int? age;
    public int? Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set
        {
            if (age == value)
                return;
            age = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Age);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a simple ViewModel with an `ObservableCollection<Person>` called `Data`. Ans, here's my XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

I checked how it's working by setting a breakpoint in the Setter for my `Age` property, and it shows the value comming in as `null`

Hope this helps ;)